# Read csv using comma separated ignore double quotes and space using streamreader

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV whose data when open in notepad looks like:

```
TEST DATA1,,,,,,
TEST DATA,,,,,,
",12:10,,10:30",,,,",,11:30",,",,12:30"
location,Value1,,Value2,,Value3
mumbai-20,1.2,,,2.3,,3.4
pune-33,1.8,,,2.34,,4.5
```

I want to read this using streamReader ignoring the commas, double quotes and spaces.

The code which i am using is

```
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"D:\Test.csv"));
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
               {
var line = reader.ReadLine();
 var array = line.Split(',');
 foreach (var element in array)
                   Console.WriteLine(element);

               }
```

Comment: `var lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\Test.csv").Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToArray();`  why not use this to read the string array elements..? also when you use the split method it breaks out the data into string[] based on your delim so not sure what you mean when you say ignore commas double quotes and spaces.. also look at `StringSplitOptions` enum

Comment: means CSV data contains double quotes and spaces as there is multiple lines of data some columns in csv are blank

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split()` is horrible, awful way to handle CSV data. There are all kinds of edge cases that it can't handle. You want a dedicated parser instead.

This replicates your sample using [my CSV parser](https://github.com/jcoehoorn/EasyCSV):

```
foreach (IList<string> row in CSV.FromFile(@"D:\Test.csv") )
{
    foreach(string element in row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

It's just one source file to include with your code.

Comment: i dont want to use CSV parser. is there a way i cant do these by streamReader?